# Docusign not prefilling documents before sending

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I am having issues when sending documents for a recipient to sign it. The documents should be prefilled using the data from my database which works fine. I know this because when I `var_dump $this->textTabs` I can see the data. `$global is false`.

The issue I am having is that when the recipient receives an email to sign the document, the fields which should be prefilled are blank. The `Data Label` matches the `tabLabel` in the code below and image [image: This image shows an example of the Data Laebl]

```
$this->textTabs = [
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'RegisteredName',
            'value' => $contactData->company->name,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'NumberOfEmployees',
            'value' => $contactData->company->employee_size,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'RegisteredNumber',
            'value' => $contactData->company->reg_no,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'SupplyAddress',
            'value' => $supplyAddress_1 . $supplyAddress_2 . $supplyCity . $supplyTown . $supplyCounty . $supplyPostcode,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'SicCode',
            'value' => $contactData->company->gapSite->scat_code,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'Recipient_UserTitle',
            'value' => $title,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'Recipient_UserName',
            'value' => $title . $firstName . $lastName,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'Recipient_Email',
            'value' => $contactData->email,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
        [
            'tabLabel' => 'ContactTelephone',
            'value' => $contactData->telephone,
            'global' => $global,
        ],
    ];

   private function send(string $status): ?array
{
    try {
        return Docusign::createEnvelope([
            'templateId' => $this->templateId,
            'emailSubject' => $this->emailSubject,
            'status' => $status,
            'templateRoles' => [
                [
                    'name' => $this->recipient['name'],
                    'email' => $this->recipient['email'],
                    'roleName' => 'Client',
                    'tabs' => [
                        'textTabs' => $this->textTabs,
                        /* 'signHereTabs' => [
                             [
                                 "xPosition" => 400,
                                 "yPosition" => 263,
                                 "documentId" => 1,
                                 "pageNumber" => 6
                             ]
                         ],
                        */
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'eventNotification' => [
                'url' => 'https://webhook.site/697fabec-145a-491f-87ce-1d62be82b298',
                'LoggingEnabled' => true,
                'RequireAcknowledgment' => true,
                'UseSoapInterface' => false,
                'IncludeCertificateWithSoap' => false,
                'SignMessageWithX509Cert' => false,
                'includeDocuments' => true,
                'includeEnvelopeVoidReason' => true,
                'includeTimeZone' => true,
                'includeSenderAccountAsCustomField' => true,
                'includeDocumentFields' => true,
                'includeCertificateOfCompletion' => true,
                'envelopeEventStatusCode' => $this->getRecipientEvents(),
                'recipientEvents' => $this->getEventNotification(),
            ]
        ]);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

The fact That recipient receives the email to sign the document, already eliminate any issue to do with my code but why is it not prefilling with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I decided to create a new docusign account and this seems to have solved the issue. I believe my account was bugger or maybe some technical issue on docusign,